# docker-compose build, how to tag image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3'
services:
        node1:
                build: node1
                container_name: node1

        node2:
                build: node2
                container_name: node2
```

Here is the Dockerfile of node1

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
COPY true.sh /var/
CMD ["/var/true.sh"]
```

node2 Dockerfile extends node1 as follows

```
FROM node1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
COPY true.sh /var/
CMD ["/var/true.sh"]
```

Now when I build images with `docker-compose up -d --build`, having initially empty local image repository, I get the following error

```
ERROR: Service 'node2' failed to build: pull access denied for node1, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

How could I define the tag, when using compose to build the images? For now, following images are built

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker_node1        latest              52dd5a083162        7 minutes ago       123MB
ubuntu              latest              113a43faa138        19 hours ago        81.2MB
```

I know I could build the images with vanilla docker, but I like the idea of having all the necessary configuration for a newcomer to bootstrap a fresh environment with a single commands, and let the same command to restart changed containers as changes are made to their builds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding the `image` directive when a `build` directive exists in a service will name and tag the built image:

```
version: '3'
services:
    node1:
            build: node1
            container_name: node1
            image: node1:latest
```